# furnace wont kick in

Tags: hvac, furnace, thermostat

My furnace seems to work intermittently. overnight its seems to stop... i have checked the thermostat and it shows says it is heating. fan is on auto, but nothing coming out.
when i turn heat to off, then back on again i can hear the furnace try to start up... however it cuts out a couple seconds later. i try that a couple of times then it seems to work again for a while...
any help would be appreciated.
A

Comment: You'll need to add more information: Is it a boiler, hot air furnace, or something else? Is it fueled by oil, natural gas, or something else?

Comment: When you say "*i can hear the furnace try to start up*", what exactly do you hear?  What is the make and model of the unit?  What does the system use for ignition (standing pilot, spark gap, hot surface ignitor etc.)?